# Aqua Data Studio: Explain Pan Appearing - How to Disable?

Tags: aqua-data-studio

In Aqua Data Stdio, the following appers on all select queries run -- I have looked high and low, and obviously missing how to turn these off. Could a kind soul provide guidance? Thank you.

Describe Error: Failed to execute EXPLAIN plan: ORA-02404: specified plan table not found

Describe Error: Failed to retrieve EXPLAIN plan: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Describe Error: Failed to DELETE EXPLAIN plan table data: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist